# Is this a bijective operator?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $T: C \left[-1, 1 \right] \rightarrow C \left[-1, 1 \right]$ be the operator defined by $(T \psi) (t) = \int_{-1} ^{t} \psi(s) ds.$ I know it is continous, but dont't know if it is bijective. I want to know this to learn if the inverse $T^{-1},$ if it exist, is countinuous or not using the open mapping theorem.

Comment: All functions in the image of $T$ are differentiable (fundamental theorem of calculus), but not all continuous functions are differentiable, so it can't be surjective.

Comment: @YourAdHere That's very clever, and it answers the question handily. May I suggest that you write it up as an answer for posterity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All functions in the image of $T$ are differentiable ([fundamental theorem of calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus)), but not all continuous functions are differentiable, so it can't be surjective.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative thought process: can you get constant functions from $T$?